# How to log only error responses in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have the following params setup on jmeter, I am running my script in a loop which is creating huge logs(jtl file), Can I log only error responses ?

[image]

Comment: which log file you are talking about? jmeter.log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure JMeter to save response data only for failed samplers by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

If you want to completely disable saving any metrics for successful samplers add the next line to the same file (however you won't be able to get reliable metrics this way):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)