# How to enable only error logs in results.jtl for a jmeter run? - NON GUI

Tags: jmeter

I am running some load test for a long duration. If i store all the results in results.jtl, memory of my system gets used fully, so i need to save only those entries which correspond to a non 200 response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log only error responses in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525811/how-to-log-only-error-responses-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
```

This way you will have response data saved only for those samplers which fail.

The same properties can be specified via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to save only errors check log/display only errors option in the [View Results tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

[image]

and you can configure the fields and remove unnecessary fields, that may reduce the size of log file

[image]

You may follow this link

[Execute JMeter Tests](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/running-jmeter-load-test/)

which will give you real time results and nice graphs at the end of tests

Comment: I am looking for options with non GUI mode